# Carrierwave : error with model.id in the store_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I'm trying to write a method to store an image from a given url, inside a ruby worker. It comes along my Rails app in which I display the object image. Here is what I've come up with:

```
@message = Message.create!
my_uploader = PhotoUploader.new
photo = open(image_url)
@message[:photo] = my_uploader.store!(photo)
@message[:photo] = my_uploader.filename
@message.save!
```

the PhotoUploader:

```
def store_dir
  Rails.env.production? ? (primary_folder = "production") : (primary_folder = "test")
  "#{primary_folder}/media/#{model.id}" 
end
```

the Message class:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :photo, :user_id
  mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader
end
```

The model.id returns an error in the storage path. The model is nil even after saving it, and the file is stored in  `#{primary_folder}/media`

Comment: it's supposed to give the id of the message into which the photo is uploaded, as the basic Carrierwave store_path suggests: `uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's that you're not calling `store!` from the model, which is why `model.id` doesn't work, because `model` is `nil`

This will probably do it for you:

```
@message = Message.create!
photo = open(image_url)
@message.photo = PhotoUploader.new
@message.photo.store!(photo)
@message.photo = @message.photo.filename
@message.save!
```

I tried this out in the rails console, and `@message[:photo].store!(photo)` gave the same error, but `@message.photo.store!(photo)` worked.

Comment: Pretty much did it!
Thanks a lot, you unloaded a real burden of mine!!